# Using counted data source in non-counted provider block in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-module, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm new to `Terraform`, I need suggestion about handling one case where I need to use data from `counted` `data-source` to `un-counted` `provider`.

I need to fetch the `gke-cluster` context and pass it to `provider helm/kubernetes` to provision resources on it .
There can be multiple `gke -clusters`, so I'm using `count` on the `data-source  google_container_cluster` and then I was trying to get the `endpoint` from it .
Like below :

```
data "google_container_cluster" "my_cluster" {
    count      = var.enabled ? length(var.gke_clusters) : 0
    location   = lookup(var.gke_clusters[count.index], "cluster_location")
    name   = lookup(var.gke_clusters[count.index], "cluster_name")
}
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {    
    host  = "https://${data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.endpoint}"
    token = data.google_client_config.provider.access_token
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
    data.google_container_cluster.my_cluster.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate,
    )    
  }
}
```

But this does not work because when I'm referring to `my_cluster` I have to specify the `index`  , and if I specify the index `my_cluster[count.index]`, I get an error that `Error: Reference to "count" in non-counted context`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I have read this correctly you are trying to target different clusters with your provider so you can then use a helm_release.

You need to have distinct providers for each cluster and differentiate them with an `alias`  so.

```
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {    
    host  = "https://my_endpoint1"
    token = "provider.access_token1"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "base64encodedcerthere1"
  }
}

provider "helm" {
  alias = "cluster2"
  kubernetes {    
    host  = "https://my_endpoint2"
    token = "provider.access_token2"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "base64encodedcerthere2"
  }
}
```

the first provider will be used where no alias is provided and the second used only where an alias is used for the provider so for example:

```
resource "helm_release" "example" {
  name       = "my-bob-release"
  ...
}
```

the above uses the default un-named provider

```
resource "helm_release" "example" {
  provider   = helm.cluster2
  name       = "my-bob-release"
  ...
}
```